# How to check if a model's association is dependent with another

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, console, associations, model-associations

I want to debug a messy app and I want to see the effective model configuration

Is there a way to see what rails know about a model in terms of its associations?

for example - if I have

```
class User

has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

I'd like to see that rails know that it will call the destroy action in the comment controller if destroy action is called in users controller

Is there a way to see in rails console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it,

it can be done with

```
User.reflections
```

which results in

```
 :comments=>
  #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0xc52abc8
   @active_record=
    User(id: integer, ...)
   @collection=true,
   @macro=:has_many,
   @name=:comments,
   @options={:dependent=>:destroy, :extend=>[]},
   @plural_name="comments">
```

which, as you can see, gives you the type of association (has_many), what it is called (:comments), the options and the plural name.

I am in :love: with this method :)

Comment: The system is flagging this answer as too terse.  Perhaps you could add a little more detail?